# Replace Weblogic Jsp Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, compiler-construction, weblogic

We recently migrated our project from IAS OJDBC to Oracle Weblogic 10.3.3. We are using Eclipse Indigo.

The problem we've run into is that some JSPs are interpreted into much larger java files than before, and for some of them the "service" function is larger than 64K after compilation, which is apparently larger than the maximum size allowed for a function in the JVM.

We've noticed with one JSP file, that the size of the old java file of the JSP that was compiled in the OJDBC server (about 5000 lines of code for the "service" function) is roughly half the size of the new file.

One solution I've found online is to "cut" the JSP into pieces and then use the "jsp:include" directive to view them as one page.

But I want to tell Eclipse or Weblogic (or both) to use a different JSP interpreter (the part that converts JSP into java), because the difference is so big.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks, Malki.

**EDIT-**

I have found this documentation: [Using the WebLogic JSP Compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jsp/reference.html#65756). Under "Precompiling JSPs" they explain about a parameter called "compilerclass" that lets you define the JSP compiler class.

The problem is that this is documentation for BEA WebLogic Server 8.1, but I am using  Oracle WebLogic Server 10.3.3. I looked for the same parameter in the documentation of 10.3.3 but couldn't find it. Does anyone know if it still exists in this version? And where I can find it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse.  It's entirely a WeebLogic issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be thinking about how to rewrite those JSPs.  I'd be appalled to find out that I was anywhere close to that 64K limit.

Comment: But that's the thing, WE WEREN'T!
The old JSP interprete's output was half the size of this new one. That's why I want to replace it and go back to working with the old one.

Comment: Scriptlet code?  Big custom tag libraries?  Still ought to get rid of them.  Weblogic's JSP compiler is the only one that matters here, because that's where the JSPs will ultimately be deployed.  I don't what Eclipse has to do with anything.  It's just an IDE.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but you still haven't answered my question. I know that Weblogic's JSP compiler is the one that matters now, that's why I'm asking if and how it can be replaced with a different one? The previous JSP compiler gave output twice as small, and thus we had no problem. And since it's all java code in the end, I see no reason why Weblogic wouldn't be able to run the compiled JSPs from a different compiler.

Comment: The reason is that WebLogic's JSP compiler is the one that's certified for use by the app server.  I'm not sure that you have a choice.